# Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed

Tags: solidity, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, coinbase

I usually send eth from my coinbase to binance with Etherium network. Unusually I encountered this error this time. I cannot really understand it because I even sent another eth to the same address with the same network, and it was completed successfully. However, I don't know where my fund is this time. Coinbase is not there to help at all. Any help would be appreciated to reach my eth.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4c8da45a7a7e7d4a358b5c7650031b55abc0a6038b87de7ee04a1195f21b2f58

Answer (score 2):

Coinbase batches their transactions to save gas on transferring assets over the Ethereum network, this transaction is just one of their batches, where they transferred ETH to a few addresses. Out of all the transfers, only the one to address `0xf5c9f957705bea56a7e806943f98f7777b995826` reverted. If it was yours, coinbase still holds your funds, and should be perfectly able to return them to you. If you transferred to another address, your funds reached their destination, and the issue is on binance's end.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I reached out to Binance, and they said they would restore the fund, but it would take several days to be reflected in my account. That was not my address.  What is annoying is that I have not received any satisfying answer from them as yours after chatting for an hour. What they said in summary is your coin left coinbase and you take care of your problem. When I asked what is different this time. If it happens again. No answer! It was quite frustrating. Again thanks a lot.